# Polyline not showing in google map android

Tags: android, native

**Problem:**
I want to show polyline between two points in google map, I do the code but it not showing the polyline between two points, I don't know what mistake I have done here.

**this is my source:**

```
      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {



        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();


        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points.clear();
            //points = new ArrayList();
            // lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);


                points.add(position);

            }

            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(12);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
             //mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

        }
        if(lineOptions!=null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Passing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Not Passing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Check whether you are getting anything in the result. Maybe your result array is blank.

Comment: i get the result while i run...

You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

Comment: Yes, you have to include API key in your request to fetch path. Otherwise, it will provide a blank list as a result. Do you want to draw a path or just a straight line?

Comment: what is the value you are getting as input in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: i want draw a path...@DharakBhatt